# The best way to use xcat head phantom in python?

Tags: python, computer-tomography, xcat

After Shepp-Logan head phantom I would like to implement xcat head phantom in python. Could you tell me what is the best way to do it. Is there a library to import or it's better to download database from site? I want to use only head part for my script so can I download only part of the xcat model?